# How to delete entity with many to many relation? JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

i don't know how to delete this. Only one thing i noticed that the OrderToProvider will be deleted after deleting all entities in a table named "OrderToProvider-Goods".

Code:

**OrderToProvider**

```
public class OrderToProvider {
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private int id;
@Basic
private int price;
@Basic
private Date dataOfOrder;
@Basic
private Date dateOfProcessing;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private main.data.Provider provider;
@ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Good> goods;
```

**Good**

```
public class Good implements Comparable<Good>{
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Basic
    private String name;
    @Basic
    private String model;
    @Basic
    private int price;
    @Basic
    private String type;
    @Basic
    private int amount;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Provider provider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the `OrderToProvider` from your DB, first you retrieve it from your DB, then `setGoods(null)` and `setProvider(null)`, then delete it afterwards. This should work with conditions that you have a properly implemented `setters`.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! May i ask one more question? But it will be pretty stupid question. How to add entity (OrderToProvider) with goods but without adding these goods in DB? It's like i can see what goods in the order, but they should not be in the DB.

Comment: I really dont know what you want to achieve here, but if what you plan on doing is save an order without saving the goods, but yet you wish to retrieve the order with some goods, am not sure that is achievable. I recommend you study how data persisting works. If you mean something else, I recommend you give a better explanation as to what you want to do, providing a scenerio if possible.

Comment: Ok, i'll try. I have order from provider with goods, and i must add it in the DB. But i don't have these goods yet. When the order with goods comes to me, after this i can add goods in the DB because i have it. it's pretty strange i know :)

Comment: You can set the goods to an emptyList() before you save the order. Try doing that.